# Is it possible to make a silverlight program as a mac OSX app?

Tags: silverlight, macos

I have a silverlight application, now I want make it run as a mac OSX app, perhaps aiming to sell on app store. Since I'm completely a newbie in mac developing, is it possible to make this silverlight app run like a native app? 
Maybe there is some way to make a browser shell, and embed that silverlight on a html to show it. is there any way make it more native without a browser control, and I want to disable the right click "silverlight" popup.

More over, since silverlight cannot access local file system directly, any good idea to do this? First came into my mind is put a webservice module in the app, so that this app acts both client(silverlight) and server, and then process the local file on server module.

Answer (score 2):

The most you can do is have it run as a Silverlight Out Of Browser application (see a bit more detailed explanation [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jprosise/archive/2009/04/05/silverlight-3-s-new-out-of-browser-applications.aspx)). This mode is pretty much like running in a chromeless browser, however it is still running in the same sandbox and you have very limited resource access.

Apps running this way will definitely not have the native OS/X app feel, neither will they be started similarly and you won't be able to sell it on the Apple App Store.

If you want to target Mac desktops and deliver a native experience I'm afraid currently Objective C or a framework on top of that is the only viable choice.